# index compatibility of dataframe with multiindex result from apply on group

Tags: pandas, dataframe, group-by, multi-index, pandas-apply

We have to apply an algorithm to columns in a dataframe, the data has to be grouped by a key and the result shall form a new column in the dataframe. Since it is a common use-case we wonder if we have chosen a correct approach or not.

Following code reflects our approach to the problem in a simplified manner.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(42)

N = 100
key = np.random.randint(0, 2, N).cumsum()
x = np.random.rand(N)
data = dict(key=key, x=x)

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

This generates a DataFrame as follows.

```
    key         x
0     0  0.969585
1     1  0.775133
2     1  0.939499
3     1  0.894827
4     1  0.597900
..  ...       ...
95   53  0.036887
96   54  0.609564
97   55  0.502679
98   56  0.051479
99   56  0.278646
```

Application of exemplary methods on the DataFrame groups.

```py
def magic(x, const):
    return (x + np.abs(np.random.rand(len(x))) + float(const)).round(1)

def pandas_confrom_magic(df_per_key, const=1):
    index = df_per_key['x'].index # preserve index
    x = df_per_key['x'].to_numpy()
    y = magic(x, const) # perform some pandas incompatible magic
    return pd.Series(y, index=index) # reconstruct index

g = df.groupby('key')
y_per_g = g.apply(lambda df: pandas_confrom_magic(df, const=5))
```

When assigning a new column to the result `df['y'] = y_per_g` it will throw a TypeError.

> TypeError: incompatible index of inserted column with frame index

Thus a compatible multiindex needs to be introduced first.

```py
df.index.name = 'index'
df = df.set_index('key', append=True).reorder_levels(['key', 'index'])
df['y'] = y_per_g
df.reset_index('key', inplace=True)
```

Which yields the intended result.

```
       key         x    y
index                    
0        0  0.969585  6.9
1        1  0.775133  6.0
2        1  0.939499  6.1
3        1  0.894827  6.4
4        1  0.597900  6.6
...    ...       ...  ...
95      53  0.036887  6.0
96      54  0.609564  6.0
97      55  0.502679  6.5
98      56  0.051479  6.0
99      56  0.278646  6.1
```

Now we wonder if there is a more straight forward way of dealing with the index and if we generally have chosen a favorable approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.droplevel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.droplevel.html) to remove first level of `MultiIndex`, such that it has the same index as `df`, then assign will working well:

```
g = df.groupby('key')
df['y']  = g.apply(lambda df: pandas_confrom_magic(df, const=5)).droplevel('key')
print (df)

    key         x    y
0     0  0.969585  6.9
1     1  0.775133  6.0
2     1  0.939499  6.1
3     1  0.894827  6.4
4     1  0.597900  6.6
..  ...       ...  ...
95   53  0.036887  6.0
96   54  0.609564  6.0
97   55  0.502679  6.5
98   56  0.051479  6.0
99   56  0.278646  6.1

[100 rows x 3 columns]
```

Comment: Looks like what we were looking for. We will use `droplevel('key')` to make it more explicit.